# WPF Set element property on Enter key pressed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, properties, triggers, keypress

i have defined custom style for my Label like code below:

```
<Style x:Key="GridLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag, Mode=OneWay}"/>

                    <Border Grid.Column="1" Name="grayborder" BorderBrush="#B2E8E4E4" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Background="White">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Name="textblock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" 
                                        Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <TextBox Name="textbox" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0"
                                        Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

                            </TextBox>

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" Name="Edit" Margin="5,0,0,0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource editicon}" Style="{DynamicResource NoStyleToggleButton}"/>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Edit" Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="textblock" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="textbox" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>

                        <!--<Setter TargetName="Edit" Property="Command" Value="{Binding UpdateElementCommand}"/>-->
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Edit" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="textblock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="textbox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>

                        <Setter TargetName="Edit" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource saveicon}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="grayborder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The main thing i want to do is to handle trigger for key press (Enter) on element name "textbox" and set property on element name "edit" to IsChecked=False.

I am using .NET 3.5 and MVVM.

Is it possible to do it without any C# code behind?

Regards

Comment: I am not aware of any way to achieve your requirements in XAML alone. There is a `KeyDown` event on the `Label` class, but there is no `EnterKeyDown` event that you could use to determine which key was pressed. For your information, it is a bad idea to set the `Template` property of a control to a `ControlTemplate` that uses an instance of itself inside as you are doing.

Comment: @Sheridan So the better way could be to create this component as separated UserControl?

Comment: By creating a `UserControl`, you can attach event handlers in the code behind to achieve your requirements. Please note that this is *not* a problem in MVVM.

Comment: @Sheridan Yes, you're right. The problem was that i have try to use only code from datacontext class which cannot handle key press event. If i use usercontrols codebehind do declare keyup handler and then notify my control class using datacontext, everything is now working fine.